# I want to insert an audio at a certain time on the video using moviepy.editor

Tags: python, ffmpeg, moviepy

I want to insert an audio at a certain time on the video using moviepy.editor, how do I do it?, or do you have another way? please show me.

Examples like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tH4LU.png)

I was expecting someone to answer me, because I searched for a long time but couldn't.

Comment: Do you know how to extract the existing audio from your movie?

Comment: I know, but every time I add it to play at 00:00, I want it to be at 00:02 or 00:03 of the video to play the sound.

Comment: You can create a `CompositeAudioClip` out of several different `AudioClips` starting st different times.

Answer (score 1):

you could use this :
clip.set_audio(CompositeAudioClip([audioclip.set_start(3)]))
and start your audio wherever you want